# How to save folder path/location

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, file-location

I want users to be able to save files to a certain location so I need to save the folder path they want. I want to do something like the way to change the download location in Google Chrome:

[image]

I know to save a file I could use `<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="file" />`
But I just need to capture the path of the folder, not save a file. How do I do this in asp.net? Then later when I do save the file, I will have the location the file needs to go.

Comment: umm I don't remember a control with that functionality but maybe you could create your own user control (try with a textbox, a file explorer/browser and a button)

Comment: what type of control is that ? is that `FileUpload` or something else. if it is `FileUpload` you can do something like this `Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);`

Comment: @coder I don't want to save a file. I just want to save a folder location

Comment: It makes no sense to save a client folder location in a web application, as you have no access to that folder in any way.

Comment: Think carefully about where your code is running. Chrome is running locally on a user machine with direct access to the file system. An ASP website runs on *your* server. It gets send data from the users local machine, but this is limited to the subset that the browsers are allowed to send based on security restrictions.

In this context, it doesn't evne make sense to choose a download location - unless you are talking about a local app which can write files to that location, which your website can't.

Comment: @CodeCaster I just want to get a folder location. So if I choose the documents folder on my computer, I want to save that path selected.

Comment: You cannot choose from serverside code where the file will be saved on the client. It works on your development machine because that machine is both server and client, so they share the same filesystem. After deployment on a real server, your code won't work anymore.

Comment: @CodeCaster The file the user will save is saved on their local machine not on server.

Comment: Again, **you cannot control where files will be saved on the client**. It just is not how HTTP and browsers work.

Answer (score -2):

i think this would help you some
first you need to import windows.forms to asp.net (aspx.cs) page.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

then take a button and generate an event to it.
use the code below it will show save as dialog box.

```
   SaveFileDialog my_Sfd1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        my_Sfd1.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";    //here you can specify the file format.(*.*)indicates all files.
        my_Sfd1.Title = "Save file to";   //Title to display at top of the dialog box
        my_Sfd1.FilterIndex = 2;
        my_Sfd1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (DialogResult.OK == (new Invoker(my_Sfd1).Invoke()))
        {
                //add file here which you want to save.
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't want to save a file. I just want to save a folder location

Comment: _"import windows.forms to asp.net (aspx.cs) page"_ - what do you think that does?

Comment: some controls they will not be in toolbox so by importing windows.forms we can also include forms toolbox elements if we remove that header file it will throw an error 
if i am incorrect pls reply the correct answer

Comment: You cannot use WinForms controls on a web application.